# Remove all tables that are below table contain certain text

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

i am getting source or remote page and manipulating it for purpose,

i am using PHP DOM, the source code i got contain many tables below each others and i want to remove all tables below a table that have td containingcertain text (Other Links:) as below

`<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr class="sectiontableheader"><td>Other Links:</td></tr></table>`

i want to remove all tables below the table above:

here is code:

```
              $url = "remote page"
              $html = file_get_contents(url);
              $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
              libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
             $doc->loadHTML($html);

             the function to remove the tables should go here
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure that the tables have the same "string representation" and you have the page code as string you could go for `str_replace($old,$new,$source)` , **however** for the DOMDocument read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) , look for getElementById/TagName after that something with remove

Comment: no they dont the same "string representation" and also no specific Id

Comment: you can select all tables, find the position of the one you need ( for example it will be the third) then delete all the tables after the 3rd element

Comment: @ ŢîganIon also position may change

Comment: well then you have to identify the tables you want to delete, find the way you can identify them in the document(common id, class ,table name ... ) , select and delete